# Angular 6 - Can't use ngModel

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using Angular 6. And I want to use ngModel like so:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="textValue">
```

On the html I was getting the following error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'
```

When I searched I learnt that I have to import FormsModule. So in my package json I added the angular forms like so:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/core": "^6.0.4",
        "@angular/forms": "^0.2.0"
   ...
```

Did a npm install and then on the app.module,

I added FormsModule to imports,

```
imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
    ],
```

But when I tried importing FormsModule from angular/forms,

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

It says:

```
Module '"PATH-TO-PROJECT/node_modules/@angular/forms/index"' has no exported member 'FormsModule'
```

What should I do to get mgModel working on Angular 6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your line of package.json:

```
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0"
```

change to:

```
"@angular/forms": "0.3.0"
```

run again:

**`npm install`**

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change in `package.json`:

```
"@angular/forms": "0.3.0"
```

and then `npm install`.

There is important information is that whenever we use `[(ngModel)]` in html tags to bind data then we must have to give name to that tag:

otherwise it will throw error: ngModel must have name property.